# Change WooCommerce Checkout Manager Datepicker to Jalali

Tags: jquery, woocommerce-offtopic

[WooCommerce Checkout Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-checkout-manager/) plugin use this for datepicker:

```
// DatePicker
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.ui.datepicker-fa', plugins_url( 'includes/pickers/di18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-fa'.'.js', WOOCCM_RELPATH ), array( 'jquery' ) );


    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', plugins_url( 'includes/pickers/jquery.ui.css', WOOCCM_RELPATH ) );
```

How can I replace it with a Jalali (Shamsi - Persian calender) datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the [plugin code](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce-checkout-manager/trunk/woocommerce-checkout-manager.php#L200), you have different options:

Date picker language is being selected based on the following code.

```
$current_language = ( defined( 'ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE' ) ? ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE : apply_filters( 'wooccm_language_code', false ) );
// DatePicker
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker', array( 'jquery' ) );
if( defined( 'ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE' ) || !empty( $current_language ) ) {
    // Check if WPML is in use or the WordPress Filter has been used
    if(
            (
                    function_exists( 'icl_register_string' ) && 
                    ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == $current_language && 
                    ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE !== 'en'
            ) || 
            !empty( $current_language )
    ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.ui.datepicker-'.$current_language, plugins_url( 'includes/pickers/di18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-'.$current_language.'.js', WOOCCM_RELPATH ), array( 'jquery' ) );
    }
}
```

- Define `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` with your required language locale(you can find supported locale [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n))
- Use `wooccm_language_code` filter hook if `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` is not defined
- Else dequeue the `-fa` script and enqueue your own

Comment: thanks for you answer. it just translate  the name of months and week days. but I looking for a way to use Jalali calendar datepicker.